# {A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message <= cannot send email using delayed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using delayed job gem and and trying to send email with delayed job.

But I failed to do that, the delayed job log always states : `{A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message`.

On the other hand, I can send email successfully if i don't use delayed job.

**The most strange thing!!! if I use delayed job to send email**

**The column `run at`of the delayed job record just created in the database
is the same as column `created at`**

code of controller:

```
def create
    @long_task = LongTask.new(params[:long_task])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @long_task.save
        # @long_task.set_delay_time(2)

        Notifier.delay.create_long_task
        # Notifier.create_long_task.deliver

        format.html { redirect_to @long_task, notice: 'Long task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @long_task, status: :created, location: @long_task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @long_task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Mailer:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.notifier.create_long_task.subject
  #
  def create_long_task
    #@greeting = "Hi"
    #@longTask ="delay setting"
    # @longTask = longTask

    mail to: "j-xxx@hotmail.com", :subject => 'Long Task Created'
  end

   handle_asynchronously :create_long_task, :run_at => Proc.new { 2.minutes.from_now }
end
```

Email templete:

```
Notifier#create_long_task

You created a long task
```